# Infinite boot after Nvidia driver installation no terminal

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia

I tried to install an Nvidia driver (unsuccessfully, I don't remember the error message) and after a restart I get an infinite loop in the startup where a screen like below is printed repeatedly. I have tried waiting for it but it never ends. I tried to do `ctr + alt + T` but it doesn't work. I have also tried modifying the screen that comes after pressing `e` in grub and modifying the linux line but none of the suggestions have worked. I either get the infinite screen below or a black screen and I can't get a terminal in either using the shortcut. Should I use boot-repair ? I don't know what to do.

[image]

Comment: You can see the message `The NVIDIA GPU 0000:01:00.0 (PCI ...) installed in this system is not supported by the 340.108`. Maybe try newer Nvidia driver that supports Your graphics card.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz would you explain how I can do that without access to a terminal ?

Comment: Can You access the grub entry via `e` and add `init 1` (at the end of linux line) to enter single user mode (root) and then boot up with `ctrl+x`?

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz Ok thanks, that brought me into recovery mode and I could get a terminal and uninstall the nvidia driver and I can boot normally now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as suggested by @MichalPrzybylowicz I just pushed `e` in grub added the `init 1` to the end of linux line and then it brought me into recovery mode. I pushed enter to get to the terminal then just ran :

1. `mount -n -o remount,rw /` (not sure if it was necessary)
2. `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*`
3. `exit`

And the system rebooted and is working fine now.